# create a drop down list in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, dropdown, xlsxwriter

I'd like to create a simple drop down list in excel using python, that contains :

- the first cell alow me to filter by year :2020   2021  2022 ..2024
- the second cell allow me to filter by month : 1  2  3 ...12

this is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
from openpyxl import Workbook
import xlsxwriter

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet('list')
wss = wb.create_sheet('year')

for number in range(1,9): #Generates 10 "date" year in the Column A;
  ws['A{}'.format(number)].value= "202{}".format(number)

data_val = DataValidation(type="list",formula1='=$A:$A') 
ws.add_data_validation(data_val)

data_val.add(wss["B1"]) # drop down list with all the values 

wb.save('date.xlsx')
```

I don't know how to complete this code , I want to have in sheet 'list ' all the years from 2020 until 2040, and in sheet 'year' to have the drop down list

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi, what code have you written so far?

Comment: If you're a beginner to Python, I would suggest working with CSV files (which can be subsequently loaded into Excel) as an easier starting point

Comment: @C_Z_ yes I add now the code

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can do this by adding making the following changes to your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import quote_sheetname

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet('list')
wss = wb.create_sheet('year')

for number in range(1,9): #Generates 10 "date" year in the Column A;
  ws['A{}'.format(number)].value= "202{}".format(number)

data_val = DataValidation(type="list",formula1='{0}!$A:$A'.format(quote_sheetname('list'))) 
wss.add_data_validation(data_val)

data_val.add(wss["B1"]) # drop down list with all the values 

wb.save('date.xlsx')
```

This will make the drop down list as the value in the first column of the sheet "list". Hope this helps.

Comment: There are 20 lines there. Please clarify what you changed. We shouldn't have to do a mental `diff` just to understand answers here. See [answer].